# User image and full name are not displaying in AdapterView?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement a search bar for a social media app that displays users with a profile image at the right, the username and the full name aligned vertically next to the image and a follow button at the bottom right that only appears if the user is not following.

I am using a Firebase realtime database to pull data from and the username displays fine but the image and the full name are not displaying and the follow Button is not the right size, as you can see from the image below:

[Wrong display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/96EOt.jpg)

While I need to achieve this:

[Correct display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x6Sgu.png)

Here is the xml for the user item that will populate the recycler view for the adapter:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp">
    <de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_profile"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:src="@mipmap/ic_launcher"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toEndOf="@id/image_profile"
        android:layout_marginStart="5dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/username"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="username"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textColor="@color/black"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/fullname"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Full Name"
            android:maxLines="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_follow"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here the User Adapter:

```
 package com.andrea.uncut.ui.Adapter;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import com.andrea.uncut.R;
import com.andrea.uncut.ui.Model.User;
import com.andrea.uncut.ui.profile.ProfileFragment;
import com.bumptech.glide.Glide;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseError;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.database.ValueEventListener;

import java.util.List;

import de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView;

public class UserAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<UserAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    private Context mContext;
    private List<User> mUsers;
    private FirebaseUser firebaseUser;

    public UserAdapter(Context mContext, List<User> mUsers) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.mUsers = mUsers;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.user_item, parent, false);
        return new UserAdapter.ViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        final User user = mUsers.get(position);
        holder.btn_follow.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        holder.username.setText(user.getUsername());
        holder.fullname.setText(user.getFullname());
        Glide.with(mContext).load(user.getImageURL()).into(holder.image_profile);
        isFollowing(user.getId(), holder.btn_follow);
        if (user.getId().equals(firebaseUser.getUid())){
            holder.btn_follow.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mContext.getSharedPreferences("PREFS", Context.MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
                editor.putString("profileid", user.getId());
                editor.apply();

                ((FragmentActivity)mContext).getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragment_container,
                        new ProfileFragment()).commit();
            }
        });
        holder.btn_follow.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if (holder.btn_follow.getText().toString().equals("follow")){
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                            .child("following").child(user.getId()).setValue(true);
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(user.getId())
                            .child("followers").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).setValue(true);
                }else{
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(firebaseUser.getUid())
                            .child("following").child(user.getId()).removeValue();
                    FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Follow").child(user.getId())
                            .child("followers").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).removeValue();
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mUsers.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public TextView username;
        public TextView fullname;
        public CircleImageView image_profile;
        public Button btn_follow;

        public ViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView){
            super(itemView);

            username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.username);
            fullname = itemView.findViewById(R.id.fullname);
            image_profile = itemView.findViewById(R.id.image_profile);
            btn_follow = itemView.findViewById(R.id.btn_follow);
        }
    }

    private void isFollowing(String userid, Button button){
        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()
                .child("Follow").child(firebaseUser.getUid()).child("following");
        reference.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
                if (snapshot.child(userid).exists()){
                    button.setText("following");
                }else{
                    button.setText("follow");
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: If you encounter problems, it's best to create a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) when posting a question. You posted more than **400** lines of code for this issue. That's a lot for people to parse and try to debug online. Please edit your question and isolate the problem, in that way you increase your chances of being helped.

Answer (score 1):

This could probably be due to ***wrap_content*** value for both the relative layout of user-item and button element.
So trying assigning fixed values to the layout and view.
Also, add font size and padding for the text in the button element to not look distorted or broken.

Comment: Thanks that helped me fix the size of the follow button but I still cannot display the profile image and  the full name